# Network bandwidth monitor

Tags: linux, bandwidth

I have a usb 3g dongle which I use from time to time by plugging it into my router so that all computers on the network can use the 3g connection (as opposed to plugging the usb into a single computer).

This 3g dongle has a monthly data limit on it which if exceeded, any data used over the limit is extremely expensive. So I need a way to track how much data/bandwidth is used when the 3g is plugged into the router so that I know when to stop using it.

After some searching I found applications like [darkstat](https://unix4lyfe.org/darkstat/) and [bandwidthd](http://bandwidthd.sourceforge.net/) but from what I can tell, these tools monitor network traffic all the time. What I need to be able to do is switch the monitoring on/off only when im using the 3g.

Basically I need to be able to plug the 3g into the router and then start the bandwidth monitor, then stop the monitor when i've unplugged it. I need to then be able to keep an ongoing record of how much bandwidth has been used each month.

It's ok if I have to add up the totals manually each time I plug in the 3g to keep a monthly running total. However if there is something that does that automatically that would be great.

Comment: What kind of router?

Comment: router: DLink - 2750U

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Off topic, but your router should be doing this for you, not monitoring software, it can most easily and reliably count bits in/out.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then `vnstat` should meet your requirements. It keeps a log of hourly, daily and monthly  network  traffic  for  the  selected  interface(s).  While it does run as a daemon, it provides `--enable` and `--disable` options for interfaces that are not constantly attached. It also has configuration options geared towards monthly billed traffic such as `MonthRotate` to set the monthly billing date, when logs should be rotated. Note: `vnstat` reads traffic information from `/proc` and `/sys` pseudofilesystems, not by sniffing packets. Therefore, after setup most operations can be run without root privileges.

Quickstart:

- install vnstat (should initialize logging for all network interfaces available at the time of installation and start the daemon)
- run `vnstat --query` and check whether the desired interface is listed (ignore "Not enough data" warnings)
- if the desired interface is not listed, you need to activate logging for it:

  - make sure that the respective interface is attached first
  - show list of available interfaces with `sudo vnstat --iflist`
  - create a database for the interface with `sudo vnstat --create --iface <interface>`
  - edit `/etc/vnstat.conf` to set the default interface (`Interface "<interface>"`)
  - restart daemon to activate logging: `sudo systemctl restart vnstat.service`
  - generate some traffic, then run `vnstat --query` again
- you may also want to remove logging for unwanted interfaces: `sudo vnstat --delete --iface <interface>`

See `man vnstat` , `man vnstat.conf` and `man vnstatd` for more information on customization and usage.